# show results in circle chart dynamic

Tags: android

I'm working in an android project in which there are some formula to get results ...

what I want here is to show the results in circle graph or chart or something like the job clean master app did 
[Here](http://www.teamapk.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/CleanMaster-android.png)

and the most important thing is that I wanna show that dynamic so when the result is 42% for example, the chart will show that. Doesn't matter if I don't show the number inside the circle ghraph

By the way I just started android proggraming

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below links that can help you to make circular progress in android..

[Circular ProgressBar Background: Android Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657086/circular-progressbar-background-android-xamarin)

[Android Circular Determinate ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776587/android-circular-determinate-progressbar)

http://karanbalkar.com/2014/05/display-circular-progressbar-in-android/

Hope it will help you..!!!

Comment: Thanks Rushabh. What you linked here is the way to create ProgressBar showing that somthing is in progress.But What I want is something to show the result and also animation or transition are not needed.I can do that using 100 pictures but that's a crazy way